# How to solve scala "reassignment to val" error?

Tags: scala

I am trying to encapsulate some code but in scala you have to directly access the variables for some reason. Why does this code not compile?

```
class MyRender {
  var camera_pitch = 0.2d
}

class MyDisplay {
  val render = new MyRender()

  def camera_pitch():Double = {
    render.camera_pitch
  }
  def camera_pitch_=(pitch: Double) = {
    render.camera_pitch = pitch
  }
}

class MyWorld {
  val display = new MyDisplay()
}

class MyEntity {
  val world = new MyWorld()
  val pitch = 4d

  def update() = {
    world.display.camera_pitch = pitch          //this fails
    world.display.render.camera_pitch = pitch   //this works
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[error] Test.scala:33:32: reassignment to val
[error]     world.display.camera_pitch = this.pitch
```

Comment: Compiles ok for me with `scalac` version 3.2.0. Are you sure the error is coming from the code above in `Test.scala` ? Shows line number 33 which doesn't exist in the snippet

Comment: @Brian I am running `2.13.1` so maybe that's the problem. the line number doesn't match since I deleted some unrelated code.

Comment: @swdev Your code doesn't compile in 2.13.1 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/rETzY9BoS0el3hXIveuUGQ/3 but compiles in 2.13.2 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/rETzY9BoS0el3hXIveuUGQ/4 Most probably it was a bug.

Comment: 2.13.2 Release notes https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/v2.13.2 Closed bugs https://github.com/scala/bug/issues?q=is%3Aclosed+milestone%3A2.13.2+

Comment: Not sure which bug/improvement specifically though.

Comment: Using variable is probably not a good idea

Comment: @cchantep  This is a video game where you need to move around. How is making the camera unmovable a good idea?

Comment: @swdev Camera can be movable but you can still model its movements in FP style (without vars).

Answer (score 0):

I copied your example code into a terminal. This fails because the var is hidden by the function, which has the same name.

You will have to pick a different variable name or function name. Scala has some interesting behaviour where variables and functions can be interchangable but this scenario isn't allowed.

I'd personally just delete this function from MyDisplay

```
def camera_pitch():Double = {
    render.camera_pitch
}
```

and in the outer code I'd call `world.display.render.camera_pitch`.

*Off-topic, but this isn't very scala-esc code as it uses a `var` as well as an OO setter/getter style which makes reasoning about multi-code performance difficult.*

Comment: I tried renaming the function using the above Scastie example with  scala 2.13.1 and it still doesn't seem to allow the getter/setter around a val.  I was able to use the old school setter `def set_camera_pitch(pitch:Double)`.